# Why does my C# Process sometimes work, and sometimes hang indefinitely?

Tags: c#, process

I've got a block of code that runs inside C# and creates a Process for decompressing (un-gzipping and un-taring) a file. On a fresh reboot of my computer, I can call the block of code below and my file is decompressed within a second or two. However, at some point, the code below completely stops working (until I do a reboot).

```
Process bashProcess = new Process();
bashProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Util.CygwinPath"];
bashProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(
    "--login -c \"tar --overwrite --gzip --directory={0} -xf {1}\"", 
    unixPath.Replace(fileName, ""), unixPath);
bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
bashProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
bashProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
bashProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
bashProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

bashProcess.Start();
bashProcess.WaitForExit(10000);
```

I've tried a few things, including:

- Grabbing the StandardOutput and logging it, to clear its buffer. (nothing was logged)
- Grabbing the StandardError and logging it, to clear its buffer. (nothing was logged)
- Killing the process afterwards (manually and programatically) in case a previous process was holding on to the file I'm decompressing.
- Deleting and reinstalling the file I'm decompressing, in case it was being held onto by a zombie process.

What could cause the Process to just not work? It doesn't error out, it just hangs indefinitely until the timeout from WaitForExit(10000) is hit.

**UPDATE**

I'm not logging the final value of **bashProcess.StartInfo.Arguments** but I have grabbed that value and ensured Cygwin can run it. When ran from Cygwin, the file decompresses as expected. The full command looks like this:

```
bash.exe --login -c "tar --overwrite --gzip --directory=/cygdrive/mypath/mydir -xf /cygdrive/mypath/mydir/myfile.tar.gz"
```

I am running the code above straight from Visual Studio 2015.

One other weird thing I've noticed on my machine is that Cygwin's boot time is variable. Right after a fresh reboot, Cygwin can be opened in seconds. After my computer has been running for a while, Cygwin can take upwards of 3 or 5 minutes to open. I wonder if Cygwin's load time and my problem in this question are related?

**UPDATE 2**

It does appear that my computer's increased slowdown of Cygwin is the source of the problem, although I don't know why Cygwin slows down over time. I noticed that my code above *did* eventually complete but it took several minutes longer than expected (code above should complete in 1-2 seconds).

Comment: What is the final value of `bashProcess.StartInfo.Arguments` when it fails? Are you logging it? When it starts happening, have you tried running Cygwin manually (outside of C#) and run that command there? What happens there?

Comment: Is this process start at logon or logon after reboot or are you literally opening VS and press F5 ?